# What is wrong with this Python game code?

Tags: python

```
import random

secret = random.randint (1,99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print ("AHOY! I'm the Dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!")
print ("It is a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries. ")

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = input ("What's yer guess? ")
    if guess < secret:
        print ("Too low, ye scurvy dog")
    elif guess > secret:
        print ("Too high, landrubber!")
    tries = tries + 1
if guess == secret:
    print ("Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did!")
else:
    print ("No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!")
    print ("The secret number was", secret)
```

I keep getting this error: if guess < secret:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
guess = input ("What's yer guess? ")
```

Calling `input` gives you back a `string`, not an `int`.  When you then compare `guess` using `<`, you need an `int` in order to compare a numerical value.  Try doing something along the lines of:

```
try:
    guess = int(input("What's yer guess? "))
except ValueError:
    # Handle bad input
```

Answer (score 6):

Because Python is strongly typed, you can't compare string and an int. What you get back from `input()` is a `str` not an `int`. So, you need to convert the `str` to an `int` before comparison is possible.

```
guess = int(input("What's yer guess"))
```

You should also handle the possible exception thrown when the input is not convertable to an `int`. So, the code becomes:

```
try:
    guess = int(input("What's yer guess"))
except ValueError:
    print ('Arrrrr... I said a number ye lily-livered dog')
```

In addition, `input()` is unsafe, at least in Python 2.x. This is because `input()` accepts *any* valid Python statement. You should use `raw_input()` instead if you're using Python 2.x. If you're using Python 3, just disregard this bit.

```
try:
    guess = int(raw_input("What's yer guess"))
except ValueError:
    print 'Arrrrr... I said a number ye lily-livered dog'
```

Comment: He's using the Python 3 `print`, so `input()` isn't an issue.

Comment: Not necessarily. `print()` is perfectly valid in Python 3. Edited to clarify anyway.

Comment: s/3/2. I meant `print` _can_ be used with the same syntax as function call in Python 2, though I do agree that it isn't often used that way.

Answer (score 1):

You spelled "landlubber" wrong.

A landrubber is a person who caresses the ground.
A landlubber is a person who doesn't know their way around a ship.

And you need to parse your input to an int before you can compare it to an int.

Comment: I so wish I could give you +1 for this :D.